# Ubuntu 14.04 bond (balance-rr) down but slaves are up

Tags: ubuntu, bonding

I am trying to setup balance-rr on my Ubuntu 14.04 server. I have a USB 3.0 dual NIC adapter (eth1 and eth2). It is direct connected to my NAS. It was working and then I rebooted and now it isn't working. I can't seem to get it to work now and I don't see anything wrong. Here are all of the files I can think that are relevant. Both of the slave interfaces appear to be working correctly but the bond is down. Is there something I am missing? Thanks!

cat /etc/modules

```
lp
rtc
bonding

# Chip drivers
coretemp
```

cat /etc/network/interfaces

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# eth1 configuration
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual
bond-master bond0

# eth2 configuration
auto eth2
iface eth2 inet manual
bond-master bond0

# Bonding eth1 & eth2 to create bond0 NIC
auto bond0
iface bond0 inet static
address 172.16.0.101
netmask 255.255.255.0
bond-mode balance-rr
bond-miimon 100
bond-slaves none
```

cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0

```
Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v3.7.1 (April 27, 2011)

Bonding Mode: load balancing (round-robin)
MII Status: down
MII Polling Interval (ms): 100
Up Delay (ms): 0
Down Delay (ms): 0
```

sudo ethtool bond0

```
Settings for bond0:
        Supported ports: [ ]
        Supported link modes:   Not reported
        Supported pause frame use: No
        Supports auto-negotiation: No
        Advertised link modes:  Not reported
        Advertised pause frame use: No
        Advertised auto-negotiation: No
        Speed: Unknown!
        Duplex: Unknown! (255)
        Port: Other
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: off
        Link detected: no
```

sudo ethtool eth1

```
Settings for eth1:
        Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: No
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                             100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                             1000baseT/Full
        Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Speed: 1000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: MII
        PHYAD: 3
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
        Supports Wake-on: pg
        Wake-on: g
        Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                       drv probe link
        Link detected: yes
```

sudo ethtool eth2

```
Settings for eth1:
        Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: No
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                             100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                             1000baseT/Full
        Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Speed: 1000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: MII
        PHYAD: 3
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
        Supports Wake-on: pg
        Wake-on: g
        Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                       drv probe link
        Link detected: yes
```

dmesg | grep "eth1"

```
[    6.259558] ax88179_178a 2-4.1:1.0 eth1: register 'ax88179_178a' at usb-0000:00:14.0-4.1, ASIX AX88179 USB 3.0 Gigabit Ethernet, 00:0a:cd:2b:c9:14
[    6.893683] bond0: Adding slave eth1
[   10.219344] ax88179_178a 2-4.1:1.0 eth1: ax88179_178a - Link status is: 1
[   10.220703] ax88179_178a 2-4.1:1.0 eth1: Write medium type: 0x013b
[   10.221713] ax88179_178a 2-4.1:1.0 eth1: link up, 1000Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0xCDE1
```

dmesg | grep "eth2"

```
[    6.588030] ax88179_178a 2-4.2:1.0 eth2: register 'ax88179_178a' at usb-0000:00:14.0-4.2, ASIX AX88179 USB 3.0 Gigabit Ethernet, 00:0a:cd:2b:c9:15
[    6.894174] bond0: Adding slave eth2
[   10.603356] ax88179_178a 2-4.2:1.0 eth2: ax88179_178a - Link status is: 1
[   10.604551] ax88179_178a 2-4.2:1.0 eth2: Write medium type: 0x013b
[   10.605743] ax88179_178a 2-4.2:1.0 eth2: link up, 1000Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0xCDE1
```

dmesg | grep "bond0"

```
[    6.664913] bond0: Setting MII monitoring interval to 100
[    6.893683] bond0: Adding slave eth1
[    6.894174] bond0: Adding slave eth2
```

Comment: Try replacing `allow-hotplug` with `auto` for all interfaces.

Comment: I originally had that, but changed it to hoping it would work. Neither are working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was hardware/driver related. I purchased a different USB 3.0 to dual gigabit adapter and installed the supplied drivers. Using the config above it works perfectly.

StarTech USB 3.0 to Dual Gigabit Ethernet Adapter (USB32000SPT) - does not work

Vantec USB 3.0 to Dual Gigabit Ethernet Network Adapter (CB-U320GNA) - works

Answer (score 1):

Replace the line `bond-slaves none` to `bond-slaves eth1 eth2` in configuration file `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Comment: I believe `bond-slaves` is only for bond mode 4. However, I did try it. Nothing changed, even the dmesg logs were the same.

Comment: Did you install paket `ifenslave`?

Comment: I did. I am starting to think that it is the USB adapter. But I installed the drivers and each NIC works, just the bond doesn't. To be safe I ordered another adapter which should arrive tonight.

Comment: Hmmm. Don't use external USB hubs for it. All USB devices can't work at one time on USB hub. Your question would be very interesting if you will add more information about used hardware.

Comment: The adapter information is on the first line of the `dmesg | grep "eth1"` output above. It is not a USB hub but a USB to dual ethernet adapter. I have to use the adapter because the computer only has one NIC and no expansion slots. The computer is an Intel NUC.